# Submit does not insert all fields in the database

Tags: angular, mongodb

In the following insert to the MongoDB database, some fields are not being inserted in the database, it is only inserting: email and password, the other fields are not and it is not throwing me any error neither in the console of the browser nor in the command console when it compiles

register.component.ts

```
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, ChangeDetectorRef, Component, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { NB_AUTH_OPTIONS, NbAuthSocialLink, NbAuthService, NbAuthResult } from '@nebular/auth';
import { getDeepFromObject } from '../../helpers';
import { EMAIL_PATTERN, NUMBERS_PATTERN } from '../constants';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngx-register',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.scss'],
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class NgxRegisterComponent implements OnInit {

  minLength: number = this.getConfigValue('forms.validation.password.minLength');
  maxLength: number = this.getConfigValue('forms.validation.password.maxLength');
  isFirstNameRequired: boolean = this.getConfigValue('forms.validation.firstName.required');
  islastNameRequired: boolean = this.getConfigValue('forms.validation.lastName.required');
  isEmailRequired: boolean = this.getConfigValue('forms.validation.email.required');
  isPasswordRequired: boolean = this.getConfigValue('forms.validation.password.required');
  redirectDelay: number = this.getConfigValue('forms.register.redirectDelay');
  showMessages: any = this.getConfigValue('forms.register.showMessages');
  strategy: string = this.getConfigValue('forms.register.strategy');
  socialLinks: NbAuthSocialLink[] = this.getConfigValue('forms.login.socialLinks');

  submitted = false;
  errors: string[] = [];
  messages: string[] = [];
  user: any = {};

  registerForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(protected service: NbAuthService,
    @Inject(NB_AUTH_OPTIONS) protected options = {},
    protected cd: ChangeDetectorRef,
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    protected router: Router) { }

  // get fullName() { return this.registerForm.get('fullName'); }
  // get email() { return this.registerForm.get('email'); }
   get password() { return this.registerForm.get('password'); }
   get confirmPassword() { return this.registerForm.get('confirmPassword'); }
  // get terms() { return this.registerForm.get('terms'); }

  get firstName() { return this.registerForm.get('firstName'); }

  get lastName() { return this.registerForm.get('lastName'); }

  get login() { return this.registerForm.get('login'); }

  get email() { return this.registerForm.get('email'); }

  get age() { return this.registerForm.get('age'); }

  get street() { return this.registerForm.get('address').get('street'); }

  get city() { return this.registerForm.get('address').get('city'); }

  get zipCode() { return this.registerForm.get('address').get('zipCode'); }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    const firstNameValidators = [
    ];
    this.isFirstNameRequired && firstNameValidators.push(Validators.required);

    const lastNameValidators = [
    ];
    this.islastNameRequired && lastNameValidators.push(Validators.required);

    const emailValidators = [
      Validators.pattern(EMAIL_PATTERN),
    ];
    this.isEmailRequired && emailValidators.push(Validators.required);

    const passwordValidators = [
      Validators.minLength(this.minLength),
      Validators.maxLength(this.maxLength),
    ];
    this.isPasswordRequired && passwordValidators.push(Validators.required);

    this.registerForm = this.fb.group({
      fullName: this.fb.control('', [...firstNameValidators]) + " " + this.fb.control('', [...firstNameValidators]),
      firstName: this.fb.control('', [...firstNameValidators]),
      lastName: this.fb.control('', [...lastNameValidators]),
      email: this.fb.control('', [...emailValidators]),
      login: this.fb.control('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6), Validators.maxLength(20)]),
      age: this.fb.control('', [Validators.required, Validators.min(1),
        Validators.max(120), Validators.pattern(NUMBERS_PATTERN)]),
      password: this.fb.control('', [...passwordValidators]),
      confirmPassword: this.fb.control('', [...passwordValidators]),
      address: this.fb.group({
        street: this.fb.control(''),
        city: this.fb.control(''),
        zipCode: this.fb.control(''),
      }),
    });
  }

  register(): void {
    this.user = this.registerForm.value;
    this.errors = this.messages = [];
    this.submitted = true;

    this.service.register(this.strategy, this.user).subscribe((result: NbAuthResult) => {
      this.submitted = false;
      if (result.isSuccess()) {
        this.messages = result.getMessages();
      } else {
        this.errors = result.getErrors();
      }

      const redirect = result.getRedirect();
      if (redirect) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          return this.router.navigateByUrl(redirect);
        }, this.redirectDelay);
      }
      this.cd.detectChanges();
    });
  }

  getConfigValue(key: string): any {
    return getDeepFromObject(this.options, key, null);
  }
}
```

register.component.html

```
<div [formGroup]="registerForm">
      <div class="form-control-group">
        <label for="input-name">Fisrt Name:</label>
        <input  nbInput
                autofocus
                fullWidth
                fieldSize="large"
                id="input-name"
                formControlName="firstName"
                [status]="firstName.dirty ? (firstName.invalid  ? 'danger' : 'success') : ''"
                [attr.aria-invalid]="firstName.invalid && firstName.touched ? true : null"
                placeholder="Full name">
        <ngx-validation-message label="Full name" [showRequired]="firstName?.errors?.required && firstName.touched">
        </ngx-validation-message>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group-group">
        <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
        <input nbInput id="lastName" formControlName="lastName" fieldSize="large"
          [status]="(lastName?.hasError('minLength') || lastName?.hasError('maxLength')) ? 'danger' : 'primary'"
          class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name">
        <ngx-validation-message label="Last Name" [showMinLength]="lastName?.hasError('minLength')"
          [showMaxLength]="lastName?.hasError('maxLength')" minLength=3 maxLength=20></ngx-validation-message>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group-group">
        <label for="inputLogin">Login</label>
        <input nbInput id="inputLogin" formControlName="login" fieldSize="large"
          [status]="(login?.errors?.required || login?.hasError('minLength') || login?.hasError('maxLength')) ? 'danger' : 'primary'"
          class="form-control" placeholder="Login">
        <ngx-validation-message label="Login" [showMinLength]="login?.hasError('minLength')"
          [showMaxLength]="login?.hasError('maxLength')" [showRequired]="login?.errors?.required" minLength=6
          maxLength=20></ngx-validation-message>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group-group">
        <label for="inputAge">Age</label>
        <input nbInput id="inputAge" formControlName="age" fieldSize="large"
          [status]="(age?.errors?.min || age?.errors?.max || age?.hasError('pattern')) ? 'danger' : 'primary'"
          class="form-control" placeholder="Age">
        <ngx-validation-message label="Age" [showMin]="age?.errors?.min" [showMax]="age?.errors?.max"
                                [showRequired]="age?.errors?.required"
                                [showPattern]="age?.hasError('pattern')" min=1 max=120></ngx-validation-message>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group-group">
        <label for="inputEmail">Email</label>
        <input nbInput id="inputEmail" formControlName="email" fieldSize="large"
          [status]="(email?.errors?.required || email?.hasError('pattern')) ? 'danger' : 'primary'" class="form-control"
          placeholder="Email">
        <ngx-validation-message label="Email" [showPattern]="email?.hasError('pattern')"
          [showRequired]="email?.errors?.required" min=1 max=120></ngx-validation-message>
      </div>

      <div class="form-control-group">
        <label for="input-password">Password:</label>
        <input  nbInput
                fullWidth
                fieldSize="large"
                id="input-password"
                formControlName="password"
                type="password"
                [status]="password.dirty ? (password.invalid  ? 'danger' : 'success') : ''"
                placeholder="Password">
        <ngx-validation-message label="Password" [showMinLength]="password?.hasError('minlength') && password.touched"
          [showMaxLength]="password?.hasError('maxlength') && password.touched"
          [showRequired]="password?.errors?.required && password.touched"
          [minLength]="minLength"
          [maxLength]="maxLength"></ngx-validation-message>
      </div>

      <div class="form-control-group">
        <label for="input-re-password">Confirm Password:</label>
        <input  nbInput
                fullWidth
                fieldSize="large"
                id="input-re-password"
                formControlName="confirmPassword"
                type="password"
                [status]="confirmPassword.dirty ? (confirmPassword.invalid || password.value != confirmPassword.value  ? 'danger' : 'success') : ''"
                placeholder="Password">
        <ngx-validation-message label="Confirm Password"
          [showMinLength]="confirmPassword?.hasError('minlength') && confirmPassword.touched"
          [showMaxLength]="confirmPassword?.hasError('maxlength') && confirmPassword.touched"
          [showRequired]="confirmPassword?.errors?.required && confirmPassword.touched"
          [minLength]="minLength"
          [maxLength]="maxLength"></ngx-validation-message>
        <p class="error-message" *ngIf="password.value != confirmPassword.value">
            Password and confirm password does not match!
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group-group" formGroupName="address">
        <label for="inputStreet">Street</label>
        <input fieldSize="large" nbInput class="form-control" id="inputStreet" placeholder="Street" formControlName="street">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group-group" formGroupName="address">
        <label for="inputCity">City</label>
        <input fieldSize="large" nbInput class="form-control" id="inputCity" placeholder="City" formControlName="city">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group-group" formGroupName="address">
        <label for="inputZipCode">Zip Code</label>
        <input fieldSize="large" nbInput class="form-control" id="inputZipCode" placeholder="Zip Code" formControlName="zipCode">
      </div>

      <!-- <div class="form-group-group">
        <label for="inputZipCode">Role</label>
          <nb-select fullWidth placeholder="Role" id="role" formControlName="role">
            <nb-option value="user">User</nb-option>
            <nb-option value="admin">Admin</nb-option>
          </nb-select>
      </div> -->

    </div>
```

console.log(this.registerForm.value);
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzzmJ.jpg)

Comment: console.log(this.registerForm.value) and add it to your question.

Comment: the console throws me all the values, there I added the result in the question

Comment: Can you show your this.service.register() code? What is being sent to mongo?

Comment: `
router.post('/sign-up', (req, res) => {
  authService
    .register(req.body)
    .then(() => res.send({ message: 'ok' }))
    .catch(err => res.status(400).send({ error: err.message }));
});
`

Comment: Thank, can you show what your are sending out in the post? Does it match the form body image you submitted?